# Check if date is holiday or not, if "holiday" the particular date cell performs another function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I want to check if date is holiday or not in excel, if "holiday" then the particular "holiday date cell" is linked to a new formula which performs a new function. Is this possible? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You can use IF(), so a small example =if(A1>B1,do_holiday,not_holiday) , do_holday is the function you want etc...

Comment: How do you know if a date is a holiday? Does the sheet contain a list of holiday dates somewhere?  What is the new formula? Could you give us a [MCVE] please?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the quick responses. I appreciate it. Btw, I use this formula to check if the inputted date is holiday or not -> =IF(OR($B$2=A12),"Holiday","Not a holiday")...
My question is that, is it possible that the particular date cell which is verified as a holiday contains a formula in the same cell with the "holiday date" cell? i.e. january 1, 2019 -> string in cell, (can it contain a new formula after the string?)

Comment: You don't need the `OR` in that formula - `=IF($B$2=A12,"Holiday", "Not a holiday")` will work.  Not getting what you mean by _is it possible that the particular date cell which is verified as a holiday contains a formula in the same cell with the "holiday date" cell_.  Can You edit your original question with extra info & screen shots?

Comment: Hi. Thank you. just uploaded a screenshot. i.e. my question, is it possible that the January 1, 2019(B2) cell contains another formula that can perform a new function? Thank you again.

Comment: I don't think so.  Depends what the new function is I guess.  In cell `B12` you could use the formula `=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A12,$B$2:$B$3,0)),"Not a holiday","Holiday")` and drag down, rather than `=IF(OR($B$2=A12,$B$3=A12),"Holiday", "Not a holiday")`

Comment: thank you @DarrenBartrup-Cook! or maybe in a particular cell, there is a new formula that is linked to the B12 to B14 cell, so that if one of the cells yield a "holiday" string it can perform a new formula? thanks in advance

Comment: This formula cold do it: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH("Holiday",$B$12:$B$14,0)),"","Your new formula here")` but I don't think that's the solution you're after.  I think this is a bit of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so would need some more context to give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could COUNT.IF the date you are analyzing appears in the range of holidays dates. If that count= 0, then it means **is not** a holiday.

> **[COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

Try something like:

`=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$3;$A12)=0;"Not holiday";"Holiday")`

Comment: Or `=IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL($A14,$A14,1,$B$2:$B$3)=0,"Holiday","Not Holiday")` if you want to include Sat & Sun as a holiday.  I don't think that's the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MATCH to check if that date appears in the list of holidays.
If it does, it will return the index in which it appears, else it returns #N/A.

We don't care where the date appears in the list of holidays, we just need to know whether it appears at all. So we can wrap the MATCH in an ISNA and then put that in an IF:

```
 =IF(ISNA(MATCH($A12,$B$2:$B$3,0)),"Not Holiday","Holiday")
```

[image]

I am not sure what you mean when you say that you want the particular "holiday" date cell to perform another function in excel.

However, I am going to assume that you just want the cell to display something other than "Holiday", depending upon a formula. If that is the case, you can simply add that formula in place of the "Holiday" text:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A12,$B$2:$B$3,0)),"Not Holiday",
    IF(X>Y,"Replace this line with","whatever function you like.")
)
```